# Enable GPS in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, gps

In my BlackBerry application, I need to enable GPS. I am using jde 5.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to RIM documentation:

- [Location-Based Services](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/lbs-summary.html)
- [Class BlackBerryLocation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/gps/BlackBerryLocation.html)

The user decides if some Location-Based Services app gets access to the device's current position via GPS.

Comment: It is better to provide some context with hyperlinks, for example the title of the linked page.

Comment: Normally i would but this user never accepts answers, and the questions are on the lines of "will you write this code for me?".

Comment: @Michael Donohue im also contemplating deleting this answer as its affecting my % of answers accepted. Since this user wont accept any answer. Thats cool with you ?

Comment: Doesn't bother me.   My earlier comment was just about including raw URLs, vs giving them a slightly nicer appearance.